# popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer not visible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've followed all the possible solutions that I found on several forum (also this: [Eclipse plugin menu item is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524270/eclipse-plugin-menu-item-is-not-visible)). But, all of them didn't resolve my problem. I've also followed this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html. Anyway the label didn't show in the menu. This is my plugin.xml:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        defaultHandler="pr.handlers.SampleHandler3"
        id="pr.commands.rightclick"
        name="Analyze">
  </command>
.....

 <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
     <command
           commandId="pr.commands.rightclick"
           label="Analyze"
           style="push">

           <visibleWhen>
  <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
     <iterate
            ifEmpty="false">
        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
           <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*java" />
        </adapt>
     </iterate>
  </with>
   </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
```

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you are looking in the Package Explorer view (not Project Explorer for example)?

Comment: Yes, what could it be? Anyway, the command exists because if I search it in the "quick access", it is on the list of command.

Comment: I worked out what was different in my test. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for Java files in the packages section of the Package Explorer there is no adapter defined for `org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile`, there is however an adapter for `org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource` so changing your `adapt` to that should work.

Since matching `IResource` will also match folders your `test` would be better checking the content type id:

```xml
   <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
      <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.contentTypeId" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaSource" />
   </adapt>
```